# Sorting doesn't work for datatype jsonstring

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Sorry but I can't understand what I am doing wrong. I get json from server and want to apply sorting for column. After rendering grid I can see that column in header is look like sorted but data a still unsorted

[image]

My javascript for grid creation is:

```
var gridDefinition = window['personalExpensesGridModel'];

gridDefinition.sortname = 'Type';
gridDefinition.sortorder = 'desc';
grid.jqGrid(gridDefinition);
```

Sorttype is defined for each column. Here you can see object for configuration:

[image]

*UPDATE1*

```
{
    "autowidth": true,
    "gridid": "RegExpGeneral",
    "url": null,
    "datatype": "jsonstring",
    "colModel": [
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "Status",
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "settingsCaption": "Status",
            "resizable": false,
            "fixed": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 25,
            "hidden": false,
            "columnSettingsType": "alwaysvisible"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "Type",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Type</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Type",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 194,
            "hidden": false,
            "columnSettingsType": "alwaysvisible"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "ExpenseCategory",
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "settingsCaption": "ExpenseCategory",
            "resizable": false,
            "fixed": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 25,
            "hidden": false,
            "columnSettingsType": "alwaysvisible"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "Description",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Description</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Description",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 91,
            "hidden": false,
            "columnSettingsType": "alwaysvisible"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "Customer",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Customer</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Customer",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 157,
            "hidden": false,
            "columnSettingsType": "regular"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "Project",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Project</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Project",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 250,
            "hidden": false,
            "columnSettingsType": "alwaysvisible"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "Activity",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Activity</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Activity",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 197,
            "hidden": false,
            "columnSettingsType": "regular"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "NotesOrAttendees",
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "settingsCaption": "NotesOrAttendees",
            "resizable": false,
            "fixed": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 25,
            "hidden": false,
            "columnSettingsType": "regular"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "Number",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Kms</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Kms",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "Global.Grid.SortNumbers",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 103,
            "hidden": false,
            "columnSettingsType": "regular"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "IntendDate",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Date</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Date",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 50,
            "hidden": true,
            "columnSettingsType": "regular"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "CostInCurrency",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Original Amount</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Original Amount",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "Global.Grid.SortNumbers",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 80,
            "hidden": true,
            "columnSettingsType": "regular"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "Vat",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Vat</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Vat",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "Global.Grid.SortNumbers",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 80,
            "hidden": true,
            "columnSettingsType": "regular"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "CostExchangeRate",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Exchange Rate</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Exchange Rate",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "Global.Grid.SortNumbers",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 40,
            "hidden": true,
            "columnSettingsType": "regular"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "Compensation",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Compensation</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Compensation",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "Global.Grid.SortNumbers",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 65,
            "hidden": false,
            "columnSettingsType": "alwaysvisible"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "CustomerPrice",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Customer price</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Customer price",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "Global.Grid.SortNumbers",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 80,
            "hidden": true,
            "columnSettingsType": "regular"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "Chargeability",
            "label": "<span title='???'>Not chargeable</span>",
            "settingsCaption": "Not chargeable",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 20,
            "hidden": true,
            "columnSettingsType": "regular"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "Actions",
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "settingsCaption": "Actions",
            "resizable": false,
            "fixed": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": 25,
            "hidden": false,
            "columnSettingsType": "noconfig"
        },
        {
            "key": true,
            "name": "TransId",
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "settingsCaption": "TransId",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": null,
            "hidden": true,
            "columnSettingsType": "noconfig"
        },
        {
            "key": false,
            "name": "IsValid",
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "settingsCaption": "IsValid",
            "resizable": true,
            "fixed": false,
            "sortable": true,
            "sorttype": "text",
            "frozen": false,
            "width": null,
            "hidden": true,
            "columnSettingsType": "noconfig"
        }
    ],
    "altRows": true,
    "width": null,
    "height": 415,
    "shrinkToFit": true,
    "jsonReader": {
        "repeatitems": false
    },
    "datastr": {
        "userdata": null,
        "total": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "records": 78,
        "rows": [
            {
                "Status": "<img src='/PXControl/Content/images/expenses/grid/pe_status_saved.png' alt='SA' title='Saved' />",
                "Type": "Travelcompclass U1 (TEST) (U1)",
                "ExpenseCategory": "<img src='/PXControl/Content/images/expenses/grid/expenses.png' alt='E' title='General' />",
                "Description": "",
                "Customer": "Construction Enterprice",
                "Project": "301952 - Syncron International AB, löpande konsultation PX Control.",
                "Activity": "10 - Ej debiterbar tid hos kund",
                "NotesOrAttendees": "",
                "Number": "",
                "IntendDate": "",
                "CostInCurrency": "",
                "Vat": "0,00",
                "CostExchangeRate": "",
                "Compensation": "3,00",
                "CustomerPrice": "0,00",
                "Chargeability": "No",
                "Actions": "<a class=\"edit-link\" data-ajax=\"true\" data-ajax-method=\"POST\" data-ajax-mode=\"replace\" data-ajax-success=\"Global.PersonalExpenses.afterAjax()\" data-ajax-update=\"#px-expenses-page-container\" href=\"/PXControl/Reg/TimeExpenses/GeneralExpense?period=201152%20%20&amp;versionCode=U&amp;transId=33024&amp;statusFilter=All&amp;doSubmit=False\">edit</a><a data-ajax=\"true\" data-ajax-begin=\"Global.PersonalExpenses.saveFormData()\" data-ajax-method=\"POST\" data-ajax-mode=\"replace\" data-ajax-success=\"Global.PersonalExpenses.afterAjax()\" data-ajax-update=\"#px-expenses-page-container\" href=\"/PXControl/Reg/TimeExpenses/Delete?period=201152%20%20&amp;versionCode=U&amp;transId=33024&amp;category=General&amp;page=General\"><img src=\"/PXControl/Content/images/expenses/grid/delete_normal.png\" /></a>",
                "TransId": "33024",
                "IsValid": "1"
            },
            {
                "Status": "<img src='/PXControl/Content/images/expenses/grid/pe_status_saved.png' alt='SA' title='Saved' />",
                "Type": "Travelcompclass U1 (TEST) (U1)",
                "ExpenseCategory": "<img src='/PXControl/Content/images/expenses/grid/expenses.png' alt='E' title='General' />",
                "Description": "",
                "Customer": "Search Engine Marketing Company",
                "Project": "301395 - Utbildning Visma Business",
                "Activity": "ANV - .",
                "NotesOrAttendees": "",
                "Number": "",
                "IntendDate": "",
                "CostInCurrency": "",
                "Vat": "0,00",
                "CostExchangeRate": "",
                "Compensation": "1 000,00",
                "CustomerPrice": "1000,00",
                "Chargeability": "Yes",
                "Actions": "<a class=\"edit-link\" data-ajax=\"true\" data-ajax-method=\"POST\" data-ajax-mode=\"replace\" data-ajax-success=\"Global.PersonalExpenses.afterAjax()\" data-ajax-update=\"#px-expenses-page-container\" href=\"/PXControl/Reg/TimeExpenses/GeneralExpense?period=201152%20%20&amp;versionCode=U&amp;transId=32735&amp;statusFilter=All&amp;doSubmit=False\">edit</a><a data-ajax=\"true\" data-ajax-begin=\"Global.PersonalExpenses.saveFormData()\" data-ajax-method=\"POST\" data-ajax-mode=\"replace\" data-ajax-success=\"Global.PersonalExpenses.afterAjax()\" data-ajax-update=\"#px-expenses-page-container\" href=\"/PXControl/Reg/TimeExpenses/Delete?period=201152%20%20&amp;versionCode=U&amp;transId=32735&amp;category=General&amp;page=General\"><img src=\"/PXControl/Content/images/expenses/grid/delete_normal.png\" /></a>",
                "TransId": "32735",
                "IsValid": "1"
            },
            {
                "Status": "<img src='/PXControl/Content/images/expenses/grid/pe_status_saved.png' alt='SA' title='Saved' />",
                "Type": "Travelcompclass F1 (F1)",
                "ExpenseCategory": "<img src='/PXControl/Content/images/expenses/grid/mileage.png' alt='M' title='TaxMileage' />",
                "Description": "$$changed price",
                "Customer": "Construction Enterprice",
                "Project": "301952 - Syncron International AB, löpande konsultation PX Control.",
                "Activity": "10 - Ej debiterbar tid hos kund",
                "NotesOrAttendees": "",
                "Number": "100",
                "IntendDate": "2011-12-27",
                "CostInCurrency": "",
                "Vat": "0,00",
                "CostExchangeRate": "",
                "Compensation": "340,00",
                "CustomerPrice": "5000,00",
                "Chargeability": "Yes",
                "Actions": "<a class=\"edit-link\" data-ajax=\"true\" data-ajax-method=\"POST\" data-ajax-mode=\"replace\" data-ajax-success=\"Global.PersonalExpenses.afterAjax()\" data-ajax-update=\"#px-expenses-page-container\" href=\"/PXControl/Reg/TimeExpenses/Mileage?period=201152%20%20&amp;versionCode=U&amp;transId=32731&amp;statusFilter=All\">edit</a><a data-ajax=\"true\" data-ajax-begin=\"Global.PersonalExpenses.saveFormData()\" data-ajax-method=\"POST\" data-ajax-mode=\"replace\" data-ajax-success=\"Global.PersonalExpenses.afterAjax()\" data-ajax-update=\"#px-expenses-page-container\" href=\"/PXControl/Reg/TimeExpenses/Delete?period=201152%20%20&amp;versionCode=U&amp;transId=32731&amp;category=Mileage&amp;page=General\"><img src=\"/PXControl/Content/images/expenses/grid/delete_normal.png\" /></a>",
                "TransId": "32731",
                "IsValid": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "scroll": 1,
    "sortable": true,
    "loadonce": true,
    "viewrecords": true,
    "userDataOnFooter": false,
    "sortname": "TransId",
    "sortorder": "desc",
    "savesettingsurl": "/PXControl/Reg/TimeExpenses/SaveGridSettings",
    "loadsettingsurl": "/PXControl/Reg/TimeExpenses/RevertGridSettings",
    "grouping": false,
    "groupingView": null,
    "rowNum": 2147483647
}
```

Comment: You posted almost no JavaScript code and no test data which you use to fill the grid. You should post *full* `gridDefinition`. The screenshort gives some information, but can't be used to reproduce your problem. You use additionally `scroll: 1`, very suspected value for `rownum`, `width: null`, unknown `onSortCol` end so on. With the callback `onSortCol: function () { return "stop"; }` for example you can prevent sorting of any column.

Comment: I commented all additional functions onSortCol and so on. Also I set scroll to 0. BUt it's still the same result. Could you tell me in what place of jquery.jqGrid.src file this sorting must be fired?

Comment: But when I run sortGrid implicity after jqgrid created, everything works fine.

Comment: The problem is not in the code of `jquery.jqGrid.src`. The problem is *in your code*. You use jqGrid in wrong way. If you want that somebody else help you you have to post the code and the test data (two lines would be enough).

Comment: Is it what i need to provide? **(UPDATE1)**

Answer (score 0):

How you could see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user157303.htm) the code which you posted has no problem with sorting:

[image]